# JavaFx Webview HTML5 DragAndDrop

Tags: java, html, swing, webview, javafx

From this code : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm

I'm loading this html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 AJAX Uploader</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ev.dataTransfer));
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="droparea"
     style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 100px; height: 100px;"
     ondrop="drop(event)"
     ondragover="allowDrop(event)">drop area</div> 
</body>
```

Normaly, I should have in the "drop" function the json object "ev.dataTransfer" with "files" property not null as it happens with normal webkit browser then do the upload (not present here).

Should I implement something more in Java ? ;(

All kinds of help will be appreciated :) thanks

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work out of the box, see here:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096939

You must handle the events on the Webview and reinject them into the browser component (WebEngine).
Below is an example. I'm using this with with Angular2 and the ng2-file-upload plugin (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload).

Use `new WebViewWithFileDragEvents(webView)` to install the events in your `WebView`. It is not pretty but works for me.

```
import static java.lang.String.format;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class WebViewWithFileDragEvents {
    private final WebView webview;

    public WebViewWithFileDragEvents(WebView webview) {
        this.webview = webview;
        this.webview.getEngine().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.webview.setOnDragOver(this::handleOnDragOver);
        this.webview.setOnDragDropped(this::handleOnDragDropped);
    }

    private void handleOnDragOver(DragEvent e) {
        Dragboard db = e.getDragboard();
        if (db.hasFiles()) {
            e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
            injectDragOverEvent(e);
        } else {
            e.consume();
        }
    }

    private void injectDragOverEvent(DragEvent e) {
        inject(join("",
                "{",
                "  var newElement=document.elementFromPoint(%d,%d);",
                "  if (window.lastInjectedEvent && window.lastInjectedEvent != newElement) {",
                "     //fire dragout",
                "     window.lastInjectedEvent.dispatchEvent(%s)",
                "  }",
                "  window.lastInjectedEvent = newElement",
                "  newElement.dispatchEvent(%s);",
                "}"),
                (int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY(), dragLeaveEvent(e), dragOverEvent(e));
    }

    private String join(String... lines) {
        return String.join("\n", Arrays.asList(lines));
    }

    private void inject(String text, Object... args) {
        webview.getEngine().executeScript(String.format(text, args));
    }

    private String dragLeaveEvent(DragEvent e) {
        return join("",
                "function() {",
                "  var e = new Event('dragleave');",
                "  e.dataTransfer={ types: ['Files']};",
                "  return e;",
                "}()");
    }

    private String dragOverEvent(DragEvent e) {
        return join("",
                "function() {",
                "  var e = new Event('dragover');",
                "  e.dataTransfer={ types: ['Files']};",
                "  return e;",
                "}()");
    }

    private String dropEvent(DragEvent e) {
        String files = e.getDragboard().getFiles()
                .stream()
                .map(File::getAbsolutePath)
                .map(f -> "{ name: '" + f + "'}")
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));

        return format(join("",
                "function() {",
                "  var e = new Event('drop');",
                " e.dataTransfer={ files: %s};",
                "  return e;",
                "}()"),
                files);

    }

    private void handleOnDragDropped(DragEvent e) {
        boolean success = false;
        if (e.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
            success = true;
            injectDropEvent(e);
        }
        e.setDropCompleted(success);
        e.consume();
    }

    private void injectDropEvent(DragEvent e) {
        inject(join("",
                "{",
                "  var newElement=document.elementFromPoint(%d,%d);",
                "  newElement.dispatchEvent(%s);",
                "}"),
                (int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY(), dropEvent(e));

    }
}
```

Comment: After injecting the events however, how do we actually handle them on the webview? the events do not seen to be triggered when I have listeners on the dropzone elements

Comment: The code above emulates the behaviour as it would be in a normal Browser but for a JavaFX webview. Basically it takes the JavaFX events and triggers them on the element under the mouse pointer int the webview. Have you tried your JS/HTML code in for instance Chrome and tested if you get the events in your JS code? If that's not working you should fix that first.

Comment: nice example exactly what i need

Comment: Hi, this solution works with files but if I need something similar for drag HTML and Images how can I do? Thanks a lot

Comment: I assume that you want to drag in elements from a Webrowser right? Because dragging in images or html from the filesystem would already be handled. You will have to modify handleOndDragDropped and dropEvent. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/Dragboard.html for the Java part of the event. For the Javascript I guess it depends what you want to do.

Comment: My problem is the dropEvent. For HTML data dnd, I can't get data. Do you know some documentation to adapt dropEvent to my needs? Thanks

EDIT: 
I want drag HTML from page to same page and it throws error with vanilla JFX. I am trying to adapt your solution to my case :)

Comment: I think to drag elements from the same window you don't need above solution, since this should be handled inside the webview, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some problems using the javafx browser example myself. In the end, I used the eclipse swt browser widget in the programs I needed this functionality. Perhaps it's worth a look.

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html

Edit: Just to add some info, this browser widget has the option of being webkit based, while still offering the ability to interact with it the way you would with javafx.